# Is a 2-hour transit time enough to catch a connecting flight in Muscat airport? Both flights are with Oman Air

Tags: transit, short-connections, muscat, oman-air

I am flying from Dubai to India with Oman Air with a layover of 2 hours at Muscat airport. Is 2 hours enough for me to catch my connecting flight from Muscat to New Delhi? My flight from Dubai to Muscat as well as the connecting flight from Muscat to New Delhi are with Oman Air. Do I need to re-check in my luggage? Am I taking a risk or should I take an earlier flight from Dubai to get more layover time to be on the safer side?

Comment: Are the two flights on the same booking?

Comment: Yes. Both flights have been made on a single booking. In fact the whole itinerary is on a single booking.

Comment: @IshaanGeorge If it wasn't doable, Oman air would not have sold you that booking.

Answer (score 7):

If you are flying via Oman Air directly to Delhi from Dubai via Muscat; then you will have plenty of time to comfortably make the transit.

This is because:

1. There are no transit formalities at Muscat.
2. From the way you have described it, both your flights are on Oman Air, so your bags will be checked through to Delhi.  You do not need to claim them again and re-check them at Muscat.
3. You will likely be given Dubai - Muscat / Muscat - Delhi boarding passes when you check in at Dubai.

Upon landing, follow the signs for transit passengers; and then look up your flight number on the monitors to see if it is listed and at what gate (this information may change from what is printed on your boarding pass).

Once you have confirmed your onward flight, simply make your way towards the gate and board your next flight.

Keep in mind airline reservation systems are aware of the minimum transit time required for terminals, so they would not have booked you a flight if the time-frame between the flight segments was not reasonable for the airport and airline combination.

In the worse case scenario - lets say there is some delay at Dubai due to weather and you land at Muscat and your flight to Delhi has already departed; you are still in the right place as Muscat is a hub for Oman Air and they will automatically reschedule you on the next available flight to Delhi.

Answer (score 1):

2 hours should be enough. Muscat isn't far from Dubai so the plane should be on time. As you are using the same airline and only transiting via Muscat, your luggages should hopefully follow you without the requirement to recheck them in at Muscat.

Comment: This really depends if the two flights are on the same booking, no?