# Less then an hour Transit in Muscat

Tags: transit, airports, short-connections, muscat

I am flying from London to Karachi via Muscat with Oman Air. The transit time is 1 hour 15 minutes both ways in Muscat. I am concerned that this is not enough time, so I started to track Oman Air flights from London to Muscat and found out that their flights arrive at least 20 minutes late pretty much every other day. In this scenario, would my transit time still be enough if the flight is delayed by 20 odd mins?

Both flights were purchased as part of 1 ticket. I bought the ticket from an online travel agent and not directly from Oman Air, as they were selling exactly the same flight for £200 extra.

Comment: Related (though concerning a longer connection):  [Whether 2 hours transit time enough to catch connecting flight from Muscat Airport. Both flights are from Oman Air](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64426/whether-2-hours-transit-time-enough-to-catch-connecting-flight-from-muscat-airpo)

Comment: I would encourage you to edit your question to address some details that might help people answer your question better:  Were both flights purchased as part of the same ticket?  Were they purchased directly from Oman Air?  Will you have any checked baggage?

Comment: Nothing in the answers to that proposed duplicate indicate whether one hour will be enough, I vote to keep this one open for now.